# Merging two accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-user, merge-accounts

I have two accounts: [2128](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/2128/francesco-turco) (old one) and [112679](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112679/francesco-turco) (new one). I'd like to merge the old one into the new one. That is, I'd like to only use the new account (112679) after the merge. I'm doing this because I can access the old account only via MyOpenID. But MyOpenID will cease functioning in february 2014.

Comment: You can always add new/extra openID providers to your old account.  Just go to your user profile, and then the "my logins" tab (just below the StackExchange header).  (See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/214632) MSO question.)

Comment: Information about merging accounts can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Thank you Arthur. I sent an e-mail as described and they merged my accounts. This question can now be marked as fixed, but I'm not sure how to do that.